# cloudfront distribution to access site hosted on framer app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

In my old implementation, my static file was deployed to the S3 bucket, and my CloudFront distribution pointed to my S3 bucket and it was all working fine.

Now, I have developed my static website on [Framer](https://framer.com/) and the URL to access it looks something like below.

`https://alive-access-XXXXXXX.framer.app/`

When I open the above URL in my browser it's working fine.

But when I add this URL to my cloud distribution instead of the S3 bucket it's not opening.

When I try to open my cloudfront distribution `https://dXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net` it looks like it's resolving properly but it's appending `index.html` at the end.

I removed the Default root object to empty but no idea from where it is appending that `index.html`.

I tried all the different options in the cloudfront distributions but it's not working.

Can someone guide me on what I need to do so that my Cloudfront distribution opens my Framer app?

Comment: After removing the **Default root object**, you got the index.html appended still. This could be the cache issue. You might not have invalidated the cache after removing the Default root object. Could you verify it?